# Difference Between JobListener, SchedulerListener and TriggerListener in quartz

Tags: java, quartz

What is exact difference in functionality of JobListener, SchedulerListener and TriggerListener.
Actually I am going to log the start and stop event of all the scheduler in my project so I am thinking about listener.

Answer (score 1):

According to **[Quartz tutorials](http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/tutorials/)** :

> ### TriggerListeners and JobListeners
>
> Listeners are objects that you create to perform actions based on
>   events occurring within the scheduler. As you can probably guess,
>   TriggerListeners receive events related to triggers, and JobListeners
>   receive events related to jobs.
>
> Trigger-related events include: trigger firings, trigger mis-firings
>   (discussed in the “Triggers” section of this document), and trigger
>   completions (the jobs fired off by the trigger is finished).
>
> ### SchedulerListeners
>
> SchedulerListeners are much like TriggerListeners and JobListeners,
>   except they receive notification of events within the Scheduler itself
>   - not necessarily events related to a specific trigger or job.
>
> Scheduler-related events include: the addition of a job/trigger, the
>   removal of a job/trigger, a serious error within the scheduler,
>   notification of the scheduler being shutdown, and others.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I want to log time when scheduler get fired then I need to use TriggerListener. Please correct me if i am wrong.